# How to post JSON with hidden form html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to post JSON object in a html hidden form.
I prepared the model object in backend and am able to get it as a pretty complicated JSON object on frontend which later is stringified. Now I need to post it. The problem is I'm not sure how convert it to form without of course looping over all attributes.

Basically I have now in my JavaScript a string like:

```
str = {"language":"en","country":"GB","objectId":24639, ...}
```

I tried to use 'data' parameter like:

```
<form enctype='application/json' action=someUrl method="post" target="_blank" name="pdfSheetForm" id="pdfSheetForm" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" value="${str}"  name="data">
</form>
```

Did not work. I'm not sure what is the problem. The goal is to post JSON exactly like str looks like, not to have sth like data : "{"language": ...}"

Comment: you either need to use template engine or have to loop through it

Comment: your `str` variable isn't a string, try `$('#hiddeninput').setAttribute('value', document.encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(str)))`

Comment: enctype [application/json](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) was abandoned. Try removing it and see if it posts correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `var str = JSON.stringify(your_object)` to make your JSON object to a simple string and on your backend you can parse that string to a JSON object again when received.

Then use `pdfSheetForm.data.value = str` to add the object data to your form as a string.